# Can a Command Buffer be reset while being executed on the GPU in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

I have the following scenario in mind and I don't know if it is valid:

1. Create a `VkCommandPool` at the beginning of the program and allocate a single `VkCommandBuffer` from it.
2. In the render loop, record commands to the `VkCommandBuffer` (implicitly resetting it) referencing the `VkFramebuffer` appropriate for the current `VkImageView` from the `VkSwapchain`.
3. Submit the command buffer

I am not sure if I can reset the command buffer and rerecord it immediately on the next frame after it has just been submitted for execution. Is this defined behavior and does it allow multiple frames in flight, or is it flawed in some way?

On one hand, it seems that this should be valid as after being submitted, the commands were copied to the GPU, but on the other hand, after seeing the flag `VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_SIMULTANEOUS_USE_BIT` it seems like by default command buffers cannot be submitted while they are already "pending".

I think this problem can be generalized to multiple command buffers and whether each of them should have as many copies there are `vkImage`s in the `vkSwapchain` or a single one would suffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Command buffers exist in [5 possible states](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-khr-extensions/html/chap6.html#commandbuffers-lifecycle): **initial**, **recording**, **executable** (can be submitted), **pending** (submitted for execution), and **invalid** (can't be used). Which operations are valid depends on which state. And what states are accessible from which other states is pretty well specified in the standard.

If you have submitted a CB, then it is in one of the following states:

- pending, if it has yet to complete execution
- invalid, if it completed execution but was one-use-only
- executable, if it completed execution and can be re-submitted

A CB which is in the pending state cannot be reset, but a CB can be reset if it is executable or invalid.

So if by "while it is being executed by the GPU", you mean "in the pending state", then no.

Note that there is no way to detect the state of a CB. It's something you have to keep track of indirectly. For example, if you submit a batch of work, you *must* assume it is pending unless you do something that synchronizes with the execution of that batch of work. That could be testing a fence (if it returns set, then the CB is no longer pending) testing a timeline semaphore, or something similar.

Comment: Thanks. I have little knowledge about the hardware. Could you explain more why a CB cannot be reset if it is submitted? Intuitively if we say something is submitted, it makes people feel it is safe to create a new one because the old one is already submitted to upstream.

Comment: @qiuweikang: You can't mess with it because you gave it to someone else to use it for a while.